# ^[\x20-\x7E]{8,127}$ except backslash

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to add one condition 'except backslash' to /^[\x20-\x7E]{8,127}$/
how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

backslash is 0x5c, so

```
/^[\x20-\x5b\x5d-\x7e]{8,127}$/
```